# Attribute directives angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I created an attribute directive to display the logo of network based on a series of numbers entered. However, I cannot get my HTML page to display anything. My project compiles, but the HTML page shows as blank. What did I do wrong?

**Below is my code for the app.component.html:**

```
<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="cardNumberInput"/>
<p>{{cardNumberInput}}</p>
<img applogo [cardType]="cardNumberInput" width="30"/>
```

**Below is my code for app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LogoDirective } from './logo.directive';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    LogoDirective
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**directive.ts:**

```
import {Directive, Input, OnChanges, HostBinding} from '@angular/core';

enum CardType { VISA = 'visa', MASTERCARD = 'mastercard', AMERICAN_EXPRESS = 'aexpress', DISCOVER = 'discover', DINERS = 'diners', UNKNOWN = 'unknown'}

@Directive({
  selector: '[logo]'
})
export class LogoDirective implements OnChanges {


  @HostBinding('src')
  imageSource;

  @Input()
  cardNumber: string;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.imageSource = 'assets/cards' + this.getCardTypeFromNumber() + '.png';
  }

  getCardTypeFromNumber(): CardType {
    if (this.cardNumber) {
      if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('34')) {
        return CardType.AMERICAN_EXPRESS;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('4')) {
        return CardType.VISA;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('5')) {
        return CardType.MASTERCARD;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('60')) {
        return CardType.DISCOVER;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('30')) {
        return CardType.DINERS;
      }
    }
    return CardType.UNKNOWN;
  }

}
```

**directive.spec.ts:**

```
import { LogoDirective } from './logo.directive';

describe('LogoDirective', () => {
  it('should create an instance', () => {
    const directive = new LogoDirective();
    expect(directive).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of mistakes in your attribute binding. Please rectify your template as below:

1. Your attribute selector name is logo not applogo
2. Your attribute input name is cardNumber not cardType
3. you are not specifying src attribute in image.

**Changes Needed**

```
  constructor(private element: ElementRef){
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    debugger;
    this.imageSource = 'assets/cards' + this.getCardTypeFromNumber() + '.png';
    this.element.nativeElement.src = this.imageSource;
    this.element.nativeElement.alt = this.imageSource;
  }

<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="cardNumberInput"/>
<p>{{cardNumberInput}}</p>
<img logo [cardNumber]="cardNumberInput" width="30"  />
```

logo.directive.ts

```
import {Directive, Input, OnChanges, HostBinding, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

enum CardType { VISA = 'visa', MASTERCARD = 'mastercard', AMERICAN_EXPRESS = 'aexpress', DISCOVER = 'discover', DINERS = 'diners', UNKNOWN = 'unknown'}

@Directive({
  selector: '[logo]'
})
export class LogoDirective implements OnChanges {
imageSource:string ='';

  @Input()
  cardNumber: string;
  constructor(private element: ElementRef){
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    debugger;
    this.imageSource = 'assets/cards' + this.getCardTypeFromNumber() + '.png';
    this.element.nativeElement.src = this.imageSource;
    this.element.nativeElement.alt = this.imageSource;
  }

  getCardTypeFromNumber(): CardType {
    if (this.cardNumber) {
      if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('34')) {
        return CardType.AMERICAN_EXPRESS;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('4')) {
        return CardType.VISA;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('5')) {
        return CardType.MASTERCARD;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('60')) {
        return CardType.DISCOVER;
      } else if (this.cardNumber.startsWith('30')) {
        return CardType.DINERS;
      }
    }
    return CardType.UNKNOWN;
  }
}

<input type="text"[(ngModel)]="cardNumberInput"/>
<p>{{cardNumberInput}}</p>
<img logo [cardNumber]="cardNumberInput" width="30"  />
```

you can see this working stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4bd23d
It is showing the alt attributes as i don't have the images.

I hope it will help.

Comment: Hey Prince, thanks for responding. I am not sure how to upload my project to StackBlitz. I am still having issues after making the corrections.

Comment: give me some time, i will add the solution for you.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a stackblitz link as well.

Comment: Hey Prince, thank you!! I can see that it works on Stackblitz, it still shows as blank for me in VSstudio, so I am not sure what's going on. But I am certain your syntax is correct if it works on Stackblitz.

Comment: Can you also let me know exactly what changes you made to the code so I know where to look?

Comment: i have added a constructor with elementRef and using this to assign src attribute inside ngOnchanges. We can discuss over chat if it doesnot resolve your issue. Added a section what changes needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209353/discussion-between-prince-and-libracorn).

Comment: Hey Prince, I'm in the chat now if you're here. Sorry I am in EST, so I was idle for some hours.